# Better design of collection structure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, nosql

I have collection with articles. I need a new collection with comments. One article can have one or more comments. Comments can have answers.

What is the better way to build it, flat or embedded?

1) Flat

```
Articles [{
    _id: 'abc123'
    content: ...
}]

Comments [{
    _id: 'comm1'
    articleId: 'abc123'
    parentCommentId: null
    comment: ...
},{
    _id: 'comm2'
    articleId: 'abc123'
    parentCommentId: null
    comment: ...
}, {
    _id: 'comm3'
    articleId: 'abc123'
    parentCommentId: 'comm2'
    comment: ...
}]
```

2) Embedded 1

```
Articles [{
    _id: 'abc123'
    content: ...
}]

Comments [{
    articleId: 'abc123',
    comments: [{
        _id: 'comm1'
        parentCommentId: null
        comment: ...
    },{
        _id: 'comm2'
        parentCommentId: null
        comment: ...
    }, {
        _id: 'comm3'
        parentCommentId: 'comm2'
        comment: ...
    }]
}]
```

3) Embedded 2

```
Articles [{
    _id: 'abc123'
    content: ...
}]

Comments [{
    articleId: 'abc123',
    comments: [{
        _id: 'comm1'
        parentCommentId: null
        comment: ...
    },{
        _id: 'comm2'
        parentCommentId: null
        comment: ...
        answers: [{
            _id: 'comm3'
            comment: ...
        }]
    }
}]
```

Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Schema design comes down to a lot of different factors.  MongoDB supports up to 16MB per document.  You don't mention how large these embedded documents will get.  Also, query access patterns and write patterns play a large role in selecting the proper schema design.  How often do you add to a sub document, remove from a sub document, or change a sub document?  How often do you query the entire document, or do you only need to query a subset, and if so, what?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. Document are quite small. It is just text comments, which are max 200 characters. When I show the article the comments will be shown. Users post comments. How often? I wish as fast as possible. :) It is a start up project. Not much now, but my goal is to have many comments per article.

Comment: Hi Podeig.  I am confused by your comment - "How often?  I wish as fast as possible.".  This response is not a number, and is not relative.  Nor does it describe access patterns such as updates, deletes, inserts, etc.  Without understanding how the data is used I cannot help.  I wish you the best!

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood. Can you explain then what you mean with "query access patterns and write patterns". I can just add that it is web site which contains article. Users will comment. It is quite common pattern. Insert, read, delete. How can I extend it that you can help me? :)

Comment: Query access patterns is merely a fancy way of saying 'how you use the data'.  As I understand it, you never update a comment, but you do allow delete of a comment.  Do you paginate data on rendering in web page?  How many comments can be added to an article?

Comment: Comment can be updated. No pagination. I suppose it can be up to 10-20 comments.

Comment: Given the small number of comments, I would extend the `Articles` collection by embedding comments as sub documents.  This means I would have one collection, not two.  This also assumes only one article will be displayed at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I think Articles collection can be huge: 100 000 articles * 10 comments each, for example. Is it not better to split them to have smaller collections?

Comment: One of the basic principles of MongoDB (or any no sql variant) is to avoid lookups and references.  This can sometimes lead to duplicate data, but performance gains can be substantial as the data is already pre-grouped together for the primary use case.  This concept differs drastically compared to RDBMS solutions where normalization is the rule.  By the way, 100,000 articles may seem large.  By my calculations if an article is 10,000 characters and has 20 comments at 200 characters each that results in roughly 14kb per document.  Roughly 1.4GB database.  Easy to fit all in memory!

Comment: Collection size does not matter as long as you have the appropriate indexes built. I've run queries against collections with millions of documents and never had any performance problems. Your primary concern is going to be with operations on your comments. MongoDB's positional operator `$` only works on the outermost array, so performing a `$push` or `$pull` on any comment that is not at the top-most level will not be possible in a tree-like embedded document structure. You will want to consider this limitation.